# New Tires and entire truck shakes after 70 mph

Tags: tires

I just had new tires put on a 2002 dodge ram and then new brakes and rotors. Took truck on highway and had shaking after 70 mph. The truck did not shake before all the new stuff. U joints are fine. Help!!!

Answer (score 7):

Take it back to where you had the tires put on, either they aren't balanced correctly or you have a bad tire (Broken Belt, out of round etc.).

Comment: I couldn't agree more.